# SharePoint 2010 Authorization Question

Tags: sharepoint-2010, authorization

Let’s say I have 2 pages in a sharepoint site. Let’s call them page A and B. We are using windows based authentication mechanism. Let’s say I have 2 already authenticated users X & Y. The page A should be visible to users who have certain attribute set to 1 in active directory. Page B should only be visible to those users that does not have this attribute set to 1. Let’s call this attribute SpecialUser. If SpecialUser is 1 for a given user, user should be able to see page A only and not be page B. If SpecialUser has any other value, user should be able to see page B only and not be page A.

In this case, user X has the attribute SpecialUser set to 1 and user Y does not. So user X should only see page A while user Y should only see page B.

There is no group in active directory that includes only users that have SpecialUser attribute value set to 1. We don’t want to create sharepoint group and add these users manually either.

Given these constraints, how can we achieve this authorization? I am thinking there may be a need for custom coding. If custom coding is required, how do I go about it. If not, what is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

If your Web Application can be setup to use Claims Based Mode instead of Classic Mode, you should be able to achieve this without custom coding, since an Active Directory attribute can be used as a claim when setting permissions on the page.

Otherwise custom coding would be required. You can create a custom web part that you place on the page, which can either redirect the user or call [SPUtility.HandleAccessDenied(new UnauthorizedAccessException())](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.handleaccessdenied.aspx) for invalid users. To security trim the pages (make them invisible), you would need similar logic in any menus or web parts that display the pages.

If the Active Directory attribute is part of the SharePoint User Profile, you can use the [UserProfile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofile.item.aspx) class. Otherwise, you can use [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/118122/How-to-use-AD-Attributes-not-represented-in-UserPr?display=Print) to retrieve the value of the attribute.

Comment: The approach to add the webpart possibly leaves a security hole if the page content can be accessed using API etc.

Comment: I am facing similar issue with my application, Is there any approach to introduce custom authorization in sharepoint or extend the sharepoint authorization.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest thing to do might be to stick with the active directory side. Sharepoint authentication can be a bit fickle. Off the top of my head I would probably suggest creating an active directory group that's meant to hold a list of these users. Rather than updating it manually you could have a service to run every so often (once a day? once an hour? depends on how long you're willing to have stale authentication) and check the user lists in active directory for this flag. The service would then update the group you're using for authentication.

There might be a way to do this more gracefully within the walls of Sharepoint development, but I've not heard of anything like it.